# How to specify content encoding for a POST request in cURL?

Tags: curl, post, encoding, character-encoding

I want to test a web service and check how it handles different character encodings when posting JSON content with `curl` like:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"foo": "bar"}' http://localhost:8080/test
```

But how can I specify the character encoding that `curl` uses to populate the HTTP request content?

It seems like `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` doesn't affect the actual content charset.

I want to test the web service with different encodings like UTF-8, ISO 8859-1 and more.